# XE2 FireMonkey - connect to a Web Service in iOS app

Tags: xcode, web-services, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I have created an XE2 FireMonkey application which needs to run on an iPad.  I am familiar with exporting to XCode and recompiling on the Mac machine.  This all works quite fine.

The problem however is when I want to connect to an existing web service.  Using the WSDL Import, I can create the necessary file and the functionality from my web service works as expected.  This only works in a Windows environment though as the file created by the WSDL Import uses the "InvokeRegistry" which is Windows specific.

How can I connect to a web service in FireMonkey in a way which will compile on XCode and work in an iOS environment?

Comment: This question might give some ideas : [can-i-call-a-web-service-from-firemonkey-for-ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718115/can-i-call-a-web-service-from-firemonkey-for-ios).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XE5 has major improvements and data connectivity is now easily handled via DataSnap.  One can easily reference existing web services via a DataSnap server, so the issues I originally had are now solved.

Answer (score 1):

The **[Web Service Toolkit](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Web_Service_Toolkit)** of Free Pascal is one option. According to [this forum post](http://groups.google.com/group/wst-list/browse_thread/thread/ac78e8d5620964bb), **iOS can be used as target platform**.

The toolkit includes a WSDL importer wizard, also available as command line tool ("ws_helper").

> "Web Service Toolkit” is a web services package for FPC, Lazarus and
>   Delphi; “Web Service Toolkit” is meant to ease web services
>   consumption and creation by FPC, Lazarus and Delphi users.

Comment: Thanks, I have downloaded an dinstalled Lazarus as well as the WST.  The WSDL importer is giving me "namespace errors" though when importing my WSDL file.  Will update this post once I have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one cannot have data connectivity in mobile iOS applications without various forms of "hacking" code.  There is currently no standard way with the XE2 framework to support this.

See: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41729